Why won't Google Chrome really or Firefox capture the network developer request of a form autopost
So imagine this code running on localhost:9080, the page does not render content but instead does a HTML auto post. But I like to use the network tab to see the HTML content rendered under the developer tools but the error I see under "Review or Source" is Could not Capture Data.
Ironically firefox does the same thing.
I was able to get the response data from cURL.
Why doesn't google chrome allow me to see the content.  I can seee the size, I thought it would have capture this.  Especially in 2024, must be some kind of bug.
Are there other tools besides wireshark or fiddler that would allow me to see the data, maybe a chrome extension that will capture ALL data and not mangle what is actually download from the server.
so in in the network traces for Chrome I cannot see the source for this but would like to.
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
<form method="post" action="/Welcome/Login" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="ACTION" value="DISP_PAGE">
</form>
</body>
</html>


Perhaps you need to enable the "persist logs" option in the dev tools

This did not work, I will see his note below.

Oh, right. yeah, Chrome dev tools are inferior to Fierfox

A browser is not a complete network capturing tool, and you can't get from
it the full request data and analyze it easily.
You need for that a full network debugger. You could use for that
Wireshark, which is a very advanced
network protocol sniffer and analyzer. On Windows you could also use
Fiddler, which might be easier
to manipulate.

Yes, and I mentioned those.  Or Charles Proxy on mac.  I was hoping not having to do all that.  I was able to do this with curl, I guess I can debug that way.
Meaning copy the curl request and do on command line.
it seems like such a simple scenario.  Maybe I will submit a google chrome patch

I just opened a chrome issue ticket, will see how they respond
